# Safari: background-clip and border-radius don't work well together

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/4tb2C/)

The `div.button` in the fiddle looks like expected in Chrome/FF but `background-clip` and `border-radius` don't work well in Safari.

[image: Div in different browsers]

Is there something wrong with code or its just how Safari behaves?

**CSS**

```
div.button {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;

    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0.8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle, #8CE2FB, #52D2F8);
    background-image:    -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle, #8CE2FB, #52D2F8);
    background-image:     -ms-radial-gradient(center center, circle, #8CE2FB, #52D2F8);
    background-image:      -o-radial-gradient(center center, circle, #8CE2FB, #52D2F8);
    background-image:         radial-gradient(center center, circle, #8CE2FB, #52D2F8);
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    -moz-background-clip: content-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to give specific size values to the gradient.
http://dabblet.com/gist/5748608 (prefix not written but added via js)

```
div.button {
   width: 100px; height: 100px;
   padding: 8px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   box-shadow: 0 0.8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   background-image: radial-gradient(center,  #8CE2FB 0, #52D2F8  52px, white 52px , white );/* oldest, includes your safari ? */
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center,  #8CE2FB 0, #52D2F8  52px, white 52px , white ); /* newest */
}
.bshad {/* box- shadow */
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0.8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3), inset 0 0 1px 8px white, inset 0 0 0 200px #52D2F8 ;
}
```

Box-shadow gives better result though.

Comment: your code is correct, but it doesn't fit fine whith abilyties of safari. So , not much choice to adapt your CSS , so it understands what you want, IMHO. For instance: IE9 doesnt understand gradient, but gets box-shadow. If your gradient turns to be a real image, put in background and hide sides with borders or inset shadow. :) matter of compromised

Comment: Well that's just bad luck. I wish some day every browser will behave as expected, especially Safari/Explorer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: they should one day, it improved a lot last couple of years